# How to send all output to a pager by default?

Tags: bash, gnome-terminal, pager

`git` has a very nice feature for many of its commands: The output on an interactive terminal is passed to a pager by default, in such a way that it only keeps the pager open if there's more than one screenful of output, and it leaves the output on the terminal instead of clearing it when you exit. Is there some way to configure this to be the default for Bash in GNOME Terminal? That is, to **send all TTY output (ideally including standard error) of every command to a pager.**

The idea is that sometimes commands unexpectedly produce tons of output (especially in case of syntax or other errors), and some of that might even be lost because of the history settings of the terminal. It would be better to get half a chance to know what actually happened by seeing the output in a pager.

Comment: How would such a system recognise commands where this should not be done? E.g. console Vim, nano, mutt, less, top

Comment: Why not just set your terminal emulator to unlimited scrollback?

Comment: @jgoldschrafe I've done that before, and it ended up filling up RAM.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know if that's possible.

The next best thing may be piping things to `less -FX`. The `-F` flag will make less quit immediately if the entire input fits on one screen, and the `-X` will make it not clear the screen after you exit.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if it is possible. But...

a couple of workaround are there:

- in `gnome-terminal` you can see previous pages with <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>PgUp</kbd> / <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>PgDn</kbd>
- if you use `screen`, you can see previous pages entering *copy mode* with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>, then moving around with <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>PgDn</kbd> and other `vi` commands (to exit from copy mode, <kbd>Esc</kbd>).

Comment: +1 for GNU Screen. I also suggest [Byobu](https://launchpad.net/byobu) (wrapper around Tmux/Screen) and its convenient F7-button to let it behave like a pager.

Answer (score 0):

`script` is a **round about way** to doing just that.  From the man page:

```
 script makes a typescript of everything printed on your terminal.  It is
 useful for students who need a hardcopy record of an interactive session
 as proof of an assignment, as the typescript file can be printed out
 later with lpr(1).
```

Comment: Close, but that doesn't actually provide a pager, which is much more handy than a separate text file, especially when running many terminals.

Comment: @l0b0: Indeed this is why I said **round about way**...

Answer (score -1):

Konsole can suspend output with <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>, all buffer in current window are freezed and able to use <kbd>PageUp</kbd> or <kbd>PageDown</kbd> to navigate.

But you need to increase buffer if necessary:

[image]

Comment: Method A is exactly what I want to avoid - Adding a pager command manually to every command. Method B won't work if the command produces output quickly - By the time I click Ctrl-S (which works in other terminals as well, by the way) output has already been lost from the terminal buffer.

Comment: @l0b0 you can increase the buffer length to i.e 5000 lines